# Drawing XML as a table in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt, dom

First of, I'd like to mention that I'm aware of XSLT and XML DOM. I'm learning XML and know the basics (proper syntax, some DOM, etc.). For efficiency purposes, I need to figure out whether to begin learning XSLT in detail first or DOM.

Here is what I'm trying to do...

A table comparing home vs. competitor:

- first column holding names of different features
- second column of a static company
- last column of a competitor that can be chosen from a drop down.

Would it be best to draw this table using XSLT or would it be better to do it using javascript ([this approach](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_to_html.asp)?

I know both are easily done, but I need to be able to make a single column visible or invisible so that only one competitor column shows up, which will make it easier for me?

Thank you!

EDIT: I have this pretty much done using data islands/tabular data control (CSV files), but since it's only IE compatible, I thought I'd learn some XML instead.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of XSLT:

```
XSLT (Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformations) is a declarative, XML-based language used for the transformation of XML documents.
```

Its designed to transform XML from one form to an other, i would use it.